# How to best avoid raising suspicions when flying direct to a country that doesn't allow dual citizenship?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, dual-nationality

Heavily edited to hopefully avoid closing of my question.

**How would a hypothetical adult female Singaporean Australian dual citizen travel directly to Singapore from Australia? Direct flights only.**

Subsequent question: **do you know people that got caught in Singapore due to the above, and what were the consequences?** were they forced to give up a citizenship, is it on the spot, do you receive a letter, can you ignore it, etc?

Maybe Reddit is the better platform to ask for people's experiences and this stackexchange is for factual answers only

Comment: The other question may be old, but the solution for this problem has not changed: you have to transit through a third country to avoid disclosing the new nationality to the country of first nationality.  This solution may be impractical and suspicious, but doing things that aren't allowed often requires impractical and suspicious measures to avoid detection.

Comment: The third country is a solution, not the solution. I don't understand the unnecessary gatekeeping when the question could bring new feedback and ideas from dual nationals.

Comment: @temp99899: typically I would agree with you but in this case the existing answer is extremely thorough and comprehensive and (as far as I can tell as a dual citizen) perfectly up to date. You can perhaps rephrase the question as "is this answer is still up to date" but the answer is pretty much "yes".

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar. I can rephrase my question to focus on the feedback of dual citizens of a country that doesn't allow dual citizenship. I'd like to know if people practically do it this way, and/or if they know of other ways, and whether they have stories of people having been caught and what were the consequences (the law say a person "may" be stripped of its citizenship but it doesn't mean they do it automatically)

Comment: But these are open-ended discussion issues...and Stack Exchange isn't a discussion forum. Read the [Help](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help) files for more. Travel.SE seeks questions with declarative answers, not those that stimulate back-and-forth discussion.

Comment: The better place to ask about the practical consequences of detection would be [Expatriates.SE].  It's off topic here.

Comment: An interesting case of how a dual citizen was caught: https://theindependent.sg/man-jailed-6-weeks-for-lying-about-citizenship-when-renewing-singapore-passport/